# Does burning graphite give off carbon monoxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Put $\pu{3.7V}$ through a graphite rod, I know graphite doesn't burn but it did smoke. So I automatically assumed it to have gave off $\ce{CO}$, so I've aired out the house $\ce{CO}$ Detector, but it did not go off. I know they only detect above $\pu{30PPM}$, but does burning heating graphite rods give off $\ce{CO}$?

Answer (score 3):

It could do - but I doubt you had enough carbon in the rod for any significant risk . Hence no detector signal.
( carbon monoxide is normally formed where oxygen is restricted in the combustion process )